element.click() doesn't do anything (Chrome extension - injected script)
I'm injecting a script which is supposed to click on an element as soon as it appears on the browser page. It is able to find the element, however .click() doesn't actually click it, despite everything else seemingly running fine.
from popup.js, works as intended.
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: targetTab},
  files: [reaction-time.js]
})

reaction-time.js , everything runs (and logs), but the button.click() doesn't click the element.
if(document.querySelector('#root')){
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer)=>{
    for(let mutation of mutations){
      if(mutation.type ==='childList'){
        console.log("Mutation detected...")
        if(document.querySelector('.view-go')){
          button = document.querySelector('.view-go')
          console.log("About to click...",button) // works
          button.click() // nothing actually happens
          console.log("clicked.") // works
        }
      }
    }
  })

  observer.observe(document.querySelector('#root'), { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

manifest.json
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "testing stuff",
  
  "short_name": "testing stuff",

  "version": "0.1.2",
  
  "description": "Collection of projects",

  
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/Sparkle_Doll.png",
    "128": "images/Sparkle_Doll.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "scripting"],

  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],

  "content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; 'unsafe-inline' 'self'"
  },

 
  "action": {
    "default_title": "testing stuff",
    "default_icon": "images/Sparkle_Doll.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "javascripts/background.js"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": [
      "*.html",
      "*.woff2",
      "*.tff",
      "images/*",
      "javascripts/*",
      "styles/*",
      "reaction-time.js"
    ],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }]
}


It should have clicked on the green area, but it did not.
Here I try it with a different element, but it still does not emulate the click.
I've gotten it working with puppeteer a while back also using the .click() function (video), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong now.
Update:
The .click() actually works on any other site I've tested this on but the one I was originally targetting. It seems like there are restrictions of some kind preventing isntances of .click() from going through. video: click() works on some sites, not on others
Solution (sort-of):
Replaced .click() with this, which works.

I don't see any debugging here that indicates you ensured calling .click on the given element actually does anything at all under normal circumstances.

Sorry, I added a link to a video of the .click() running as intended on the same element under normal circumstances.

does that same result happen if you do it from the dev tools console, the same way your extension is doing it? (i would assume it does, but testing this will at least prove what you're expecting to happen is what should be)

You could try with this approach

It may be https://crbug.com/40215987.

I've done some more testing - I was able to successfully run the click() on other websites via devtools console and the extension. I guess there's something on the site I was originally targetting preventing .click() from actually going through.
I switched out .click() for this approach , which works, so I'll use that for now.
thanks guys
